# How to test In App Subscription in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

I've integrated In app purchase api(v3) in my existing app successfully. I've also created in app subscription in google play and added subscription id in code. In Google developer website i've read that to test in app purchase we need to add email id's in Settings section. So i've added test email id's there and saved it(please see the attached image). Then i've purchased the subscription successfully but money got deducted from my google wallet account. Is there any thing that i missed to configure in google play or am i doing any thing wrong. Please help me.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. We can't test in app subscriptions, but we can test in app products. So we can test it as real transaction using google wallet then we can refund that amount and cancel the subscription in google merchant account. This way we can test in app subscriptions.

[image]

Comment: Note that this behaviour changed sometime in February 2015. Now, accounts with testing access will receive the message `This is a test subscription. It will recur daily. You will not be charged` when trying to buy in-app subscriptions. This also means that all subscriptions seem to be "billed" daily.

Comment: For my part, testing product works fine. But testing subscription break my google account. It seems that the purchase flow is not complete (and the purchased subscription return an empty object in my code). After testing a subscription, I cannot cancel it.

Comment: Hi @Tobliug, you can cancel your subscriptions either in google merchant account or in google play app.

Comment: Hi @ramesh6233
I am currently in discussion with google support team, because I cannot cancel this subscription. I always get an error when I click on Cancel button. In fact, this test subscription contains no data. (same issue on 2 google accounts)

Comment: @Tobliug, Did you find a solution for this? I am currently facing the same issue. I am not able to cancel the test subscription

Comment: @Sammys,  Unfortunately not... I just give up for the moment and still have this issue with my account.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.Not able to cancel the subscription. And now i am getting new error that is "item  you requested is not available for purchase."

Comment: @StefanAnca: If I set billing period on monthly basis, it still gives message about daily recurrence when I am testing. Is it bug or normal behaviour ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar It seems that all test subscriptions are billed daily, this is normal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189461/test-subscription-feature-of-in-app-billing/29012571#29012571 for more information

Answer (score 6):

In Google devloper account in **setting-->ACCOUNT DETAILS--->LICENSE** **TESTING** add testing user email id with comma for more than one testers

1. Publish your app in Alpha Mode
2. Again Add testers email id in OPEN ALPHA TESTING or CLOSED ALPHA TESTING **At ALPHA CONFIGURATION SECTION-->MANAGE TESTERS**
3. You will get Opt-in URL =https://play.google.com/apps/testing/Your package name just share it with the Testers
4. Tester will get link to download app ,just download apk and test subscription
5. First of all it will ask for card information just put information **don't worry** **it will not charged for Alpha Testing transactions**