# Google developer console -Test account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-app purchase in my app, i need to test my app,i pay the money using in-app purchase and i assume Google will return it back when account is test account.

Question is how i have to add the test account,there are two ways in the Google developer console to add test account,

1)Google developer console -> settings -> "License Testing"

2)Google developer console -> open any app -> APK -> "ALPHA TESTING / BETA TESTING"

Please explain what is the purpose of above two and which one i have to use

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta/Alpha Testing is used to test your build by testers or your team before sending it to production. To test InApp Purchase you need to provide gmail account's in Setting-->API access-->License Testing. Once you add your gmail account there then you can purchase items without paying any amount. The transaction happens through that gmail account will be considered as testing. Please note you can't test in app subscriptions, but you can test in app products. for more info please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278982/how-to-test-in-app-subscription-in-android/26280255#26280255).

Thank you